# Automate download file from sharepoint without installing any software

Tags: sharepoint

Is there anyway that I can automatically download files from MS sharePoint when a file is created or modified without installing anything(e.g. connection gateway of power automate)?

Comment: It appears to be a stock functionality (there is a button "Synchonize Folder" on the toolbar in the document library). https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-and-teams-files-with-your-computer-6de9ede8-5b6e-4503-80b2-6190f3354a88 But this does not appear to be a programming question and is likely to be closed as such.

Answer (score 0):

To download files from MS sharePoint when a file is created or modified, you can build a Power Automate flow like below:
[image]